# Joomla Template Manager not updating list of templates

Tags: templates, joomla

I just updated my 1.5.26 site to 2.5.6 using jUpgrade. I made a backup of my old custom template which I also updated to the new version.  Problem I am having is that the template manager is not updating the list of templates. Here is what I see:

- If I delete a user template folder I am not using, for example the Beez5, the list of templates is not updated.
- My old template, which I updated and update the templateDetail.xml file is not recognized.
- I copied the default Atom template folder and made changes to the templateDetails.xml file and the template list still does not recognize the new template.

I am running this on my Mac using Mamp Pro 2.0.5.  I have error reporting at system default and do not see anything in the error logs.

I also tried downloading a fresh version of 2.5.6 and updating configuration.php with same issues.

Comment: If you delete a template by simple deleting the folder. it will still appear in the list as the name is still stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that templates work very differently in 2.5 than in 1.5. They act much more like normal extensions and must be installed and uninstalled using the the extension manager. You can't just delete the files a you could have in 1.5 just like you can't just put the files in place.
Also 2.5 adds the concept of template styles. These are essentially sets of parameter settngs that are stored in the template_styles table. You must delete the styles as well as uninstall the template itself.
If you made a copy of Atomic by usng the templae copy button in the template manager template vew a new style for your copy will automatically be inserted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To find a copy of a template, you could use *Extension Manager > Discover* :

1. Purge Cache
2. Discover
3. Install

If you want to refresh Joomla after you've updated templateDetails.xml use *Extension Manager > Manage* :

1. Find the template in the list
2. Mark it and use *Refresh Cache*